# Asynchronous Function in child_process's execFile in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, phantomjs, casperjs

In a node.js (casperJS script) file, the function `execFile` from module `child_process` is used to run a script `mongoScript.js` that access a Mongodb database collection.

```
execFile("node", 'mongoScript.js', null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", stdout);
    console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr));
    finished = true;
});
```

where `mongoScript.js` contains an async function `collection.find`

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs')
var db = mongojs()
var collection = db.collection('myCollection')

collection.find({}, function(err, docs) {       
    console.log('done')
    db.close()
})
```

**Problem:** It appears that the script is exited before `collection.find` have a change to print `done`. How can we make it wait for `collection.find` to finish running?

Comment: what are you getting console.log(stdout);

Comment: @user111111111 nothing

Comment: I think if you bind to `stdout.on('data', doSomething)` then Node will realize that it is pending async operations until you close the pipe, and thus remain open. That said... i thought it would do the same thing because you passed a callback to execFile...

Comment: @Plato seems like this is an issue with CasperJS/PhantomJS. I ran the parent .js script again using node instead of casperjs and the child process exited.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/) says, the `args` argument of the `execFile` function is supposed to be an array:

```
execFile("node", ['mongoScript.js'], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", stdout);
    console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr));
    finished = true;
});
```

If it is not an array, JavaScript probably tries to split the string into an array in which case `node m o n g o ...` is actually called.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
exec("node mongoScript.js"+childArgs,function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", stdout);
    console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr));
    finished = true;
});
```

Comment: I had to pass some arguments, and `exec("node mongoScript.js", childArgs, function (err, stdout, stderr) { ... }` gave the same problem.

Comment: Thats some improvement! It doesnt seem to exit the exec of `node mongoScript.js` now.... using `return` does not seem to exit the process

Comment: Not yet... the node script is not exiting

Comment: write exit() after db.close()

Comment: Still does not exit, even when the `mongoScript.js` file contains only `exit()`

Comment: `process.exit()` and `process.exit(code=0)` also does not work

Comment: just run and wait for some time

Comment: i set the wait timeout to 20 secs, still not returning

Comment: Seems like this is an issue with running the parent .js using `casperjs`. When I ran the parent .js file using `node`, the child process exited. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder what version of PhantomJS you're using, because [`exec()` is not implemented](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/modules/child_process.js#L56-L62).